# Backbone.Model save -- returned model's child is array not Backbone.Collection.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Model that looks like:

```
var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            id: null,
            items: new PlaylistItems()
        };
    }
});
```

where PlaylistItems is a Backbone.Collection.

After I create a Playlist object, I call save.

```
playlist.save({}, {
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        console.log("model:", model, response, options);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

In here, my model is a Backbone.Model object. However, its child, items, is of type Array and not Backbone.Collection.

This was unexpected behavior. Am I missing something? Or, do I need to manually pass my array into a new Backbone.Collection and initialize this myself?

Comment: Backbone by default doesn't support saving/sync'ing of Collections, so what's likely happening is that after the model makes it's roundtrip the resultant JSON array is used as is.  Collections are intended to be collections of `Model`s (intended for managing their own persistence).  If PlaylistItems are children of an aggregate root then you likely shouldn't be using a Collection to begin with.

Comment: I am calling Save on a Model not on a Collection. I don't think it's unreasonable to have a child Collection of a Model load during a save... are you saying that Backbone considers that bad practice? If so, do you know why? This seems like a common 1 to 0+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kind of depends on what your server is expecting and what it responds with.  Backbone does not know that the attribute `items` is a Backbone Collection and what to do with it.  Something like this might work, depending on your server.

```
 var Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            id: null,
            items: new PlaylistItems()
        };
    },
    toJSON: function(){
        // return the json your server is expecting.
        var json = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this);
        json.items = this.get('items').toJSON();
        return json;
    },
    parse: function(data){
        // data comes from your server response
        // so here you need to call something like:
        this.get('items').reset(data.items);
        // then remove items from data: 
        delete data.items;
        return data;
    }

});
```

Comment: How come you delete data.items before returning? Wouldn't it make more sense to modify data.items such that it is a Backbone.Collection?

Comment: The object you return from parse gets `set()` on the model, so if you created a new Collection and return that, the model would have a new collection instance for `items`.  If you had hooked up a 'reset' event or anything else to the previous Collection instance, it would no longer work. Calling `reset()` with the new json keeps the same instance, so a 'reset' event handler would still get hit.

Comment: Would saying data.items = new PlaylistItems(data.items); and then returning data achieve the same result? Or something different? If different, could you explain why? I think I understand but I want to make sure..

Comment: Now, if you have access to change the REST API you could and maybe should do what @Matt suggested and create endpoints for the individual playlist items.  Then when you add a playlist item you would use `playlistItems.create()` with the new item's json passed in.

Comment: `data.items = new PlaylistItems(data.items)` creates a new instance. It would break if you had some event handler somewhere else in your code like `playlist.get('items').on('reset', doSomethingOnReset)` because this was hooking up to the instance you replaced.